# pymysql encoding error while inserting binary data into longblob column

Tags: python, mysql, pymysql

I'm trying to insert contents of a binary file into a longblob column:

**Python code:**

```
conn = pymysql.connect(...)
cursor = conn.cursor()
with open('test.bz2', 'rb') as fp:
    data = fp.read()
cursor.execute('insert into test_t (test) values (%s)', [data])
```

***Error stack trace:***

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./doit2", line 9, in <module>
    cursor.execute('insert into test_t (test) values (%s)', [data])
  File "/u02/srm_tp/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pymysql/cursors.py", line 127, in execute
    result = self._query(query)
  File "/u02/srm_tp/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pymysql/cursors.py",     line 275, in _query
    conn.query(q)
  File "/u02/srm_tp/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 763, in query
    sql = sql.encode(self.encoding)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'latin-1' codec can't encode character '\udcae' in position 45: ordinal not in range(256)
```

Create table script:

```
mysql> show create table test_t;
+--------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Table  | Create Table                                                             |
+--------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| test_t | CREATE TABLE `test_t` (
  `test` longblob
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci |
+--------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Default Encoding:

```
=->python3 -c 'import sys; print(sys.getdefaultencoding())'
utf-8
```

Adding "charset='utf8', use_unicode=True" to connect call, changes the error to:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./doit2", line 13, in <module>
    cursor.execute('insert into test_t (test) values (%s)', [data])
  File "/u02/srm_tp/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pymysql/cursors.py", line 127, in execute
    result = self._query(query)
  File "/u02/srm_tp/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pymysql/cursors.py", line 275, in _query
    conn.query(q)
  File "/u02/srm_tp/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 763, in query
    sql = sql.encode(self.encoding)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't encode character '\udcae' in position 45: surrogates not allowed
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like it was a pymysql bug. I upgraded from 0.6.4 to 0.6.6 (latest as of now) and the issue is no longer there.

Answer (score 2):

[This](http://www.dasprids.de/blog/2007/12/17/python-mysqldb-and-utf-8) should do the trick:

```
conn = pymysql.connect(...)
conn.set_character_set('utf8')
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute('SET NAMES utf8;') 
cursor.execute('SET CHARACTER SET utf8;')
cursor.execute('SET character_set_connection=utf8;')
with open('test.bz2', 'rb') as fp:
    data = fp.read()
cursor.execute('insert into test_t (test) values (%s)', [data])
```

Comment: pymysql doesn't have set_character_set function. I tried adding "charset='utf8', use_unicode=True" to the connect call, and the error changed to: UnicodeEncodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't encode character '\udcae' in position 45: surrogates not allowed

Comment: Try to connect with `charset="utf8"`, ex: `db = pymysql.connect(host="localhost", user = "root", passwd = "", db = "testdb", use_unicode=True, charset="utf8")`

Comment: Yep, I did. Sorry, hit Enter before I finished typing the response. Now I'm getting: UnicodeEncodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't encode character '\udcae' in position 45: surrogates not allowed

Comment: Try to run `yourstring.encode('utf-8')` before you try putting it into the database.

Comment: That's the weird part - I am not dealing with strings here. The file is open as binary, and when I read from it - "data" is bytes.

Comment: Wow. Found the issue. Looks like it was a bug in pymysql. I had version 0.6.4 I installed a couple of months ago - just upgraded to 0.6.6 and all is working.